# The remainder of the real number

Tags: java, double

When I tried this Code:

```
double d=1.23;
        System.out.println(d%1);
```

The output was: `0.22999999999999998`

My Question is: Why?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that double is not accurate.
The long answer is to understand that you should learn the [way double stored in memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

if you want to do accurate calculations, i would use `BigDecimal` object of java

```
    BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("1.23");
    System.out.println(num.remainder(new BigDecimal(1)));
```

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. As of now, this answer doesn't tell the OP what they're doing wrong, how to fix it, and so on.

Comment: edited, added suggestion